# Wordpress pagination does not show

Tags: wordpress

For a new WordPress template I coded a loop that works fine. But there is no pagination. Does anyone see, why there is no pagination shown?
Thanks!

My loop:

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

                    $args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'post',
                            'numberposts' => -1,
                            'posts_per_page' => 9,
                            'paged' => $paged,
                            'cat' => '4'
                            );
                                                                        
                        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                                                                        
            if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                                            $the_query->the_post();
                ?>

                                ......
            <?php
                    }
} else { echo 'no posts found';  }
                                                                                                                wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

And on the bottom of the page:

```
<?php the_posts_pagination( array( 'mid_size'  => 2 ) ); ?>
```

Comment: please remove `'numberposts' => -1,` form `args array`. you can try another way also as described in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'pagination' ) ) :
  function pagination( $paged = '', $max_page = '' ){
    global $wp_query
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    if( ! $paged )
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    if( ! $max_page )
    $max_page = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    
    echo paginate_links( array(
      'base'       => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link( $big ))),
      'format'     => '?paged=%#%',
      'current'    => max( 1, $paged ),
      'total'      => $max_page,
      'mid_size'   => 2,
      'prev_text'  => __('«'),
      'next_text'  => __('»'),
      'type'       => 'list'
    ) );
  }
endif;
```

And the loop template will be like -

```
  $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;        $args = array(
      ''post_type' => 'post',
      'posts_per_page' => 9,
      'paged' => $paged,
      'cat' => '4'
    );
    
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
      while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
      
      get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
      
      endwhile;
       
      pagination($paged, $loop->max_num_pages);// Pagination Function
      
      endif;
      wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Thanks Rajat but I receive two notices and the output stops after the first article. The notices are: 1)  Undefined variable: wp_query in ... on line 86
that would be then:
$max_page = $wp_query->max_num_pages;


2) Trying to get property 'max_num_pages' of non-object in... on line 86 (I mentioned the line already) Any idea?

Comment: hello @rabox66, please have a look my updated answer. Please add `global $wp_query` top of the `pagination` function definations and use `pagination` function like ` pagination($paged, $loop->max_num_pages);`.